# beta epiphany-browser (Web Browser), comand line auto start?

Tags: raspbian, terminal, web-browsers

I am running Raspbian, and I am trying to setup a "kiosk mode" box. I have successfully done this with midori, but midori does not support html5. so I wanted to try the new beta "web browser" (seems to run epiphany-browser).

my current setup is like this: `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`:

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@midori -e Fullscreen -a http://www.playr.biz/23612/15122
```

this new web browser is discussed [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/5535)

but when I look at the manpage, it does not say much about CLI options.

```
man epiphany-browser
```

so, my question is: how can I start the epiphany-browser in full screen mode, and start a specific URL like I have done with midori above? (if possible at all).

update: I followed advice and I tried the following in file /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

```
@epiphany-browser http://www.playr.biz/5dd1/1ddd5
@sleep 2s
@echo key F11 | xte
```

but it did not make it full screen, so I tried to run xte manually, but got an error " Unable to open display 'default'"

so, I did two things, I changed the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and I looked for this line:

```
xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms
```

then I changed it to:

```
xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms :0
```

to define the display/screen as :0 (localhost number 0)

now, if I run this

```
echo key F11 | xte -x:0
```

the screen goes full screen.

but, when I update the `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` like this:

```
@epiphany-browser http://www.playr.biz/5ddd/1dddd
@sleep 60s
@echo key F11 | xte -x:0
```

PS: I tried 2s, 10s, 60s and 120s, but that did not help.

So I guess the @sleep 60s might not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your problem, but it is a suggestion based on the context.

> I am trying to setup a "kiosk mode" box. I have successfully done this with midori, but midori does not support html5.

Chromium (a fork of chrome) is available for the pi, supports HTML 5, and although it is undocumented, has a `--kiosk` mode.  I tested this on the raspbian, but I imagine it is in the Arch and Pidora repos as well:

```
> apt-get install chromium
```

A surprisingly small download, < 100 MB.  Then:

```
> chromium --kiosk
```

Presto, full screen.  There does not seem to be a way to get it out of full screen (F11 doesn't work), but perhaps that is the point of kiosk mode.

Initially, chromium has a *residential memory* footprint (i.e., actual RAM usage) of ~70 MB.

Comment: tested this now, and the kiosk mode works as adverticed, but my html5 video still complains.

Comment: The HTML5 video standard looks to involve the usual mess of legal infighting over what formats are supposed to be supported; AFAICT [reading this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats) the result is there *aren't any that are required*, lol.  If it is H.264, there's a note there that it was removed from chromium (but not chrome) which is a shame since the pi has hardware acceleration for that.  Firefox might (have you tried that?), although firefox doesn't seem to have a fullscreen/kiosk mode except via F11.

Comment: I guess FF is next on my list :)

Comment: FF did the trick.. but also chromium was very usefull, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't look like there's a way to do it directly, but the [xte](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte) tool can be used to simulate a key press.

```
epiphany-browser http://www.playr.biz/23612/15122
sleep 2s # give it time to start
echo key F11 | xte # simulate pressing the full screen key
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try  this. I would vote you up, but I have no karma on this one. (raspberry pi)

Comment: I installed xautomation to get xte, but when I try to run xte I get this error message "Unable to open display 'default' tried to google it, but so far nothing

Comment: Try "DISPLAY=:0 echo key F11 | xte" instead.

Comment: yes did that, thanks.. helped. now I only need to make the delay work :)

Comment: I think the problem may be the @. According to the ArchWiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Autostart_files), that's used for processes that need to continuously be restarted if they crash, which means that whole file is executed non-linearly. That is to say the sleep doesn't actually do anything. Put it all into a bash script to ensure linear execution, and have the autostart file call that, so that if it does crash it gets restarted.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you helped me a lot, and your answer actually answered my question, even if I ended up using a different browser for now.

Comment: if I could mark both as the correct answer I would :( and I have no carma to even upvote this solution. sorry

Comment: anyone know how to keep epiphany from reopening the last session? Can't figure how to disable such a useful and annoying "feature"

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a digital picture frame using epiphany kiosk style:
http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2015/04/rpicframe-html5-kiosk-style-picture.html

You will need a window manager opened before launching. matchbox-window-manager is light weight

The -a in the CLI will load it in kiosk mode:

```
sudo -u pi epiphany-browser -a --profile ~/.config http://localhost/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick here is to include the sleep command in the automation script instead of depending on `/bin/sleep`.

My `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` looks like this and seems to work as intended:

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@epiphany-browser index.html
@xte 'sleep 10' 'key F11'
```

Of course you should replace '`index.html`' with a real URL and you still need the `xautomation` package.