# Render a HTML5 Website with no interface

Tags: video, web-browsers, web

Let me just start by saying i no nothing about raspberry pi.. But I want to get into, for a specific project, but before that i just want to know if this project is possible. So here is the list of questions:

1. Main Question: can i render an HTML 5 website on a raspberry pi with out a user interface?
2. would that website render be able to play video smoothly?
3. would it be able to handle css3 transitions?
4. Which model of the raspberry pi would be suitable for this?

I'm sorry if these questions are stupid, but like i said i know nothing.

Any Help would be Greatly Appreciated...

**UPDATE**

thanks for all the feedback so for, but look the end goal here is, to have raspberry pi connected to a monitor and displaying that website on the monitor without any browser user interface.. i hope this clears the question up.

Comment: A browser renders HTML (5) and CSS. A web server sends the HTML and CSS for your browser to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to run a browser in "kiosk mode", i.e. automatically start the browser, and run a website fullscreen without the normal web browser tool bars and menus showing.

This ought to be possible: various browsers are available for the RPi that support HTML5 and CSS3. Midori seems to be used a lot for this type of task, and has good [kiosk mode instructions](https://wiki.xfce.org/midori/faq#kiosk_mode). [This set-up](http://www.niteoweb.com/blog/raspberry-pi-boot-to-browser) seems to be similar to what you want to do.

Playing video may cause more problems. The RPi is powerful enough for video playback, but whether video works in a web browser will depend on the browser and the video format. Not all HTML5 browsers have full support for the HTML5 video standard.

The answers to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14454/beta-epiphany-browser-web-browser-comand-line-auto-start) may also be helpful.

You are likely to want a Model B or B+ Raspberry Pi because it has more memory, comes with a wired ethernet port, and has more USB ports (in case you need to add a wifi dongle).

Comment: Yes thats it! thanks ive got a starting point now!

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving video over your LAN, there should be no  problem.  As others have pointed out, if you want to serve video via your ISP, there may be a bottleneck. Many, if not most, ISPs won't let you run any server (if they know of itl And generally have very limited uplink speeds.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment mentions, a browser renders HTML (5) and CSS. A web server sends the HTML and CSS for your browser to render.

The Raspberry Pi (all models) can run as a server. There are [instructions](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md) on the how to install Apache on the Raspberry Pi. Just google "Raspberry Pi apache" and you will get a bunch of info.

If the Pi can host a Media Server, then I am willing to bet it can serve up some videos nicely. I haven't tried it, but there are a few people that have. [Here is one](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=45681).

Comment: it can serve vids, but the question should be does the connection have the upstream(outbound) bandwidth to support that.

Comment: @Tyson - I agree. I am willing to bet no. From what I have read is that the Pi has limited bandwidth over either and/or Wifi

Comment: The greatest bandwidth bottleneck will most likely be the modem to outside world hop, where bandwidth is limited to what level of service has been paid for.  My pi can do MUCH more than it does, but the upsteam pipe is 1M due to the plan I'm willing to pay for.

Comment: please see update.