# Web server autostart

Tags: server, php

I have some project in php ( including sql ). What server should I use for it?
When the pi will started It need to autostart server and open browser in fullscreen without url bar and other tools, only my project.

More informations about my project:

- I have web application written in php that stores data in sql database
- I will use touch display on my raspberry
- It will be for public use, so It can show only my application and nothing else

Now what I need:

> - How to autostart server and what server should I use-
> - How to autostart web browser that is running my app fullscreen without any other tool from browser itself

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberrypi.SE I believe that the question will be hard to answer without additional information. Feel free to edit the question to add more details to help people to give useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install and configure PHP5, a SQL server and a HTTP server with CGI capability. And then setup a browser to start automatically in fullscreen mode, loading your web application.

**SQL server:**

If your database code is MySQL compatible, I would recommend the [MariaDB Server](http://blog.pi3g.com/2014/07/easy-mariadb-installation/). Or you can use a the [MySQL Server](http://www.raspipress.com/2014/06/tutorial-install-mysql-server-on-raspbian/).

**HTTP server:**

It sounds like you only want to access the PHP web project with the browser locally on your RPi. In that case, it might be the easiest solution, to [use the built in webserver of PHP](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-5-4-built-in-webserver).

But if you want to access your web application from the internet, I would recommend to install a full blown server like [apache](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server/step7/Install-Apache-with-PHP/), [nginx](http://xmodulo.com/lightweight-web-server-raspberry-pi.html) or [lighttpd](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/light-webserver).

You can add the command to start the PHP build-in webserver to the file `/etc/rc.local`. This way, it would start automatically. The other full blown servers will most likely be configured to start automatically.

**Browser:**

For the automatic start of a fullscreen browser in LXDE, you can have a look at [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14454/beta-epiphany-browser-web-browser-comand-line-auto-start). But there are problems with the fullscreen mode. So maybe go with the chromium browser like int [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14463/10657) to the same question.